# How to mute push notification when we press mute button

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, mute

I'm developing app in objective-c and I'm planning to add functionality of mute in it. how to make app push notifications mute on button press and unmute as well after clicking on button.

Comment: This is very broad question. We won't write the code for you, so why don't you try reading the documentation and come up with specific questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. You can read the user`s Push Notification settings, but can´t set them from your app.

Comment: How whatsApp is making it?

Comment: they probably set a flag on their servers that you dont get a notification. But they dont send a notification then block it.